# Why do I get duplicate items in Xcode's auto-complete?

Tags: xcode, autocomplete

I often get duplicate prototypes in my Xcode auto-complete lists.  Am I misunderstanding something?  Have I inadvertantly changed some setting?

Here's a picture:[image]

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653786/why-do-all-these-duplicate-items-appear-in-the-xcode-autocomplete

Comment: @GregorySieranski: Thank you!  That makes sense...  It's annoying... but it makes sense.